# Alpha Vantage (Yahoo Fin alt) & Pandas Dataframe Issue - .days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, alpha-vantage

Looking into alternatives now that Yahoo finance finally seems like it's gone for good. Came across [Alpha Vantage](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage) which looks very interesting. The code below is running up until I try to find the delta between the start and end date, but I get the error below:

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
ts = TimeSeries(key=key, output_format="pandas")
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily("AAPL",outputsize="full")
days = (data.index[-1]- data.index[0]).days
```

output:

```
days = (data.index[-1]- data.index[0]).days
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I've also tried:

```
days = (float(data.index[-1])- float(data.index[0])).days
```

and

```
days = (int(data.index[-1])- int(data.index[0])).days
```

Printed dataframe head as asked below

```
print(data.head())
```

Output:

```
             open     low   close    high     volume
2000-01-03  104.87  101.69  111.94  112.50  4783900.0
2000-01-04  108.25  101.19  102.50  110.62  4574800.0
2000-01-05  103.75  103.00  104.00  110.56  6949300.0
2000-01-06  106.12   95.00   95.00  107.00  6856900.0
2000-01-07   96.50   95.50   99.50  101.00  4113700.0
```

No luck with anything, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try: `(data.index[-1].astype(np.datetime64) - data.index[0].astype(np.datetime64)).days`

Comment: Also, posting a snippet of your dataframe would help.

Comment: @COLDSPEED unfortunately I've tried that previously with no success as well. Get the following error, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'astype'" I've also added the head of the dataframe just to give some more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear your index is a string. Convert it to datetime like this using `df.index.astype`:

```
In [1165]: df.index = df.index.astype(np.datetime64)
```

Now, what you're doing will work:

```
In [1166]: (df.index[-1] - df.index[0]).days
Out[1166]: 4
```